# Weird effects with AddEquation

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to render multiple radial gradients, with the goal of their colors adding up where they overlap. I'm doing a very simple three.js code for that, see [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/gfh07qpr/4/).

However, I'm getting an unexpected effect - the borders of overlapping gradients seem to be making the other gradients ***darker***, see the dark lines in this screenshot:

[image: WEirdBanding]

I don't understand why this is happening. If I understand the OpenGL documentation correctly, GL_FUNC_ADD should simply ***add*** the component values (and, I assume, clamp to 1.0). I'm using GL_SRC_ALPHA and GL_ONE (or rather, their equivalents in three.js) for source/destination factors, e.g.

```
    const mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        alphaMap: grad2,
        blending: THREE.CustomBlending,   // Similar with THREE.AdditiveBlending
        blendEquation: THREE.AddEquation,
        blendSrc: THREE.SrcAlphaFactor,
        blendDst: THREE.OneFactor,
    });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doing what you want, I think. The borders are not darker, it is other areas that are brighter.

Comment: I looked into it closer, and you're right, it's just what the math does with a linear-brightness gradient.

Comment: It looked the way I wanted after I changed the linear distance-from-center to square of that.